# Residuals are not normally distributed in linear regression model

Tags: regression, residuals, qq-plot

I have a linear regression model and residuals look like this:

[image: Residuals QQ plot]

what does it mean for my model? Is my model inappropriate because residuals are not normally distributed?

Comment: Since there are several possible reasons for such a display (problems with either the mean or the variance specification can do it, for example), that plot *on its own* doesn't necessarily tell us very much.

Comment: Tails are fat, you have to take that into account when estimating confidence intervals of parameters.